# MySql XNOR equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql, operators

I'm writing a SQL query which checks for incorrect equipment in its `where` clause. In order to perform this operation I need to check each of the equipment's revision cycles one by one, so this clause would limit the results to correct equipment (not having any of the cycles incorrect):

```
where not exists(select * from trevision_cycle cycle 
    where cycle.id_equipment = equip.id and cycle.`status` = 'NO_OK')
```

However, now I want to introduce a query parameter in order to retrieve only the correct equipment or only the incorrect equipment, depending on its value. Let's say I call it `incorrect`, so I would like to do **the same as what's done here**:

```
where (not incorrect and not exists(select * from trevision_cycle cycle 
    where cycle.id_equipment = equip.id and cycle.`status` = 'NO_OK'))
or (incorrect and exists (select * from trevision_cycle cycle 
    where cycle.id_equipment = equip.id and cycle.`status` = 'NO_OK'))
```

So, if the `incorrect` flag is present, check for equipment having at least one incorrect revision cycle. Otherwise, retrieve only the equipment having all of them correct. **The query looks quite redundant** though and the same result could be achieved with a logical [XNOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate).

Do I have a better choice for this?

**Update**

Sample data

```
Equipment 1 -> Has one NO_OK cycle
Equipment 2 -> All its cycles are OK

Query with incorrect = true -> Returns only Equipment 1
Query with incorrect = false -> Returns only Equipment 2
```

Comment: can you some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: The second query clause does exactly what I want. All in all, I guess MySql might have some operator/function to achieve the same result without having to repeat the inner query.

Comment: You can check the profiler, but I suspect that the inner query is cached the first time it runs.  You can consider optimizing with an index if it is not write heavy.  My question is what is the purpose of this data?  Are you looking to do a merge/upsert?  If so, there is probably a better way.

Comment: @rfportilla not at all, just a query to generate a report. The problem is not only about performance, but about readability too..

Comment: the query is easier than you think. you should show some sample data though.

Comment: @vkp done. Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing [This Fellow's](https://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/sql-nand-xnor/) blog, if you were to create the function XNOR like so:

```
--XNOR
CREATE FUNCTION XNOR (@a bit, @b bit) RETURNS bit AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @a ^ @b ^ 1
END
```

Then you could simplify your statement using it as so:

```
where dbo.XNOR(incorrect, exists(select * from trevision_cycle cycle 
        where cycle.id_equipment = equip.id and cycle.`status` = 'NO_OK'))
```

EDIT: My apologies, for MySQL, you would have to create the function using its XOR instead of '^' ('^' is the XOR function for SQL Server).  I'm uncertain if the rest of the syntax is correct for MySQL, but you get the idea:

```
--XNOR
CREATE FUNCTION XNOR (@a bit, @b bit) RETURNS bit AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @a XOR @b XOR 1
END
```

If you have reason not to make up a new function to do this, then the following is logically equivalent:

```
where incorrect XOR exists(select * from trevision_cycle cycle 
        where cycle.id_equipment = equip.id and cycle.`status` = 'NO_OK') XOR 1
```

Comment: Will give it a try, thanks! How the hell is this not included in MySql functions?? x(

Comment: I guess not many people need XNOR.  It doesn't exist natively in SQL Server either (not sure about Oracle).  If you don't want to create a new function (or if you don't have permissions to do so), then, following the function's logic, using this WHERE statement should be just as good! :
`where incorrect XOR exists(select * from trevision_cycle cycle 
        where cycle.id_equipment = equip.id and cycle.status = 'NO_OK') XOR 1`

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `XOR` with `NOT` - both exists in mysql. This is truth table for `XOR`:

```
+----------------+
|A | B | A XOR B |
+--+---+---------+
|0 | 0 | 0       |
|0 | 1 | 1       |
|1 | 0 | 1       |
|1 | 1 | 0       |
+----------------+
```

If we apply `NOT` to this table, it will look this:

```
+---------------------+
|A | B | NOT(A XOR B) |
+--+---+--------------+
|0 | 0 | 1            |
|0 | 1 | 0            |
|1 | 0 | 0            |
|1 | 1 | 1            |
+---------------------+
```

Same as the `XNOR` table. So, `WHERE` can look like this:

```sql
WHERE NOT (incorrect XOR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM trevision_cycle cycle 
WHERE cycle.id_equipment = equip.id AND cycle.`status` = 'NO_OK'))
```